# How to add a custom activity to SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sfsafariviewcontroller

I want to add a custom activity (`UIActivity`) to a `SFSafariViewController` that I am presenting in my app. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. Create a subclass of `UIActivity`.

Implement all [required methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/) of the class, and when initializing the activity, pass in the URL of the page at that point and initialize your `UIViewController`, as `prepareWithActivityItems:` isn't called within the `SFSafariViewController` context ([rdar://24138390](http://openradar.appspot.com/24138390)). If your activity doesn't show UI, instead save the URL during initialization so you can process it when the user taps the action.

Full example:

```
@interface YourActivity : UIActivity {
    UIViewController *activityViewController;
}
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url;
@end


@implementation YourActivity

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self prepareWithURL:url];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)activityType
{
    return @"YourTypeName";
}

- (NSString *)activityTitle
{
    return @"Perform Action";
}

- (UIImage *)activityImage
{
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourActionIcon"];
}

- (BOOL)canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
    NSURL* url = nil;
    for (NSObject* obj in activityItems)
    {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]])
        {
            url = (NSURL*)obj;
        }
    }
    
    [self prepareWithURL:url];
}

- (void) prepareWithURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    // initialize your UI using the given URL
    activityViewController = ... // initialize your UI here
}

- (UIViewController *)activityViewController
{
    return activityViewController;
}

+ (UIActivityCategory)activityCategory
{
    return UIActivityCategoryShare;
}


@end
```

## 2. Add `UIActivity` to `SFSafariViewController`

Implement the following method in your `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate`, which initializes the activity and passes in the URL of the page the user is viewing.

```
- (NSArray<UIActivity *> *)safariViewController:(SFSafariViewController *)controller
                            activityItemsForURL:(NSURL *)URL
                                          title:(NSString *)title
{
    YourActivity* activity = [[YourActivity alloc] initWithURL:URL];
    return @[activity];
}
```